# Script : set in bold highest value

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I got an array in Google Sheet that looks something like this :

```
+-----+---------+------------+------------+------------+-----+
|     |    A    |      B     |      C     |      D     | ... |
+-----+---------+------------+------------+------------+-----+
|  0  |         | Mission #1 | Mission #2 | Mission #3 | ... |
+-----+---------+------------+------------+------------+-----+
|  1  | Item #1 |     100    |     250    |     250    | ... |
+-----+---------+------------+------------+------------+-----+
|  2  | Item #2 |     200    |    1000    |     500    | ... |
+-----+---------+------------+------------+------------+-----+
|  3  | Item #3 |     300    |    3000    |     800    | ... |
+-----+---------+------------+------------+------------+-----+
| ... |   ...   |     ...    |     ...    |     ...    | ... |
+-----+---------+------------+------------+------------+-----+
```

I want to create a script that bold the highest value for each item. But there is a problem, as you can see, some items get the same value in different missions, what I need is in this case, only the "most right" needs to be bold.

So what I expect to do :

```
+-----+---------+------------+------------+------------+-----+
|     |    A    |      B     |      C     |      D     | ... |
+-----+---------+------------+------------+------------+-----+
|  0  |         | Mission #1 | Mission #2 | Mission #3 | ... |
+-----+---------+------------+------------+------------+-----+
|  1  | Item #1 |     100    |     250    |   **250**  | ... |
+-----+---------+------------+------------+------------+-----+
|  2  | Item #2 |     200    |  **1000**  |     500    | ... |
+-----+---------+------------+------------+------------+-----+
|  3  | Item #3 |     300    |  **3000**  |     800    | ... |
+-----+---------+------------+------------+------------+-----+
| ... |   ...   |     ...    |     ...    |     ...    | ... |
+-----+---------+------------+------------+------------+-----+
** = is bold
```

So I started to think :

- `var Item1High = max(b1;d1);`
- `For each row (X1) if value == Item1High then set to bold`

But at this state the most difficult part is to set in bold only the most right value (So the highest value of row)
And I'm stuck at this state.

Could you help me with that ? 
I'm using Google Sheet Script in JavaScript.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to set the bold type to the maximum value in each row of Google Spreadsheet.
- For example, when the column "B" and "C" is the same value and the maximum value, you want to set the bold to the column "C".
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

The flow of this sample script is as follows.

#### Flow:

1. Retrieve all values from the sheet.
2. Create text styles.
3. Set the created text styles.

#### Sample script:

Before you run the script, please set the sheet name.

```
function myFunction() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1";

  // 1. Retrieve all values from the sheet.
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const range = sheet.getDataRange();
  const values = range.getValues();
  values.shift();

  // 2. Create text styles.
  const tempStyle = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle().setBold(false).build();
  const bold = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle().setBold(true).build();
  const styles = values.map(r => {
    r.shift();
    let ar = Array(r.length).fill(tempStyle);
    ar[r.lastIndexOf(Math.max(...r))] = bold;
    return ar;
  });

  // 3. Set the created text styles.
  range.offset(1, 1, styles.length, styles[0].length).setTextStyles(styles);
}
```

#### References:

- [newTextStyle()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#newtextstyle)
- [setTextStyles()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#settextstylesstyles)

### Added:

In this sample script, the selected range is used.

```
function myFunction() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1";
  const selectRange = "B2:D4";  // Please set the range you want to use.

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const tempStyle = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle().setBold(false).build();
  const bold = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle().setBold(true).build();
  const range = sheet.getRange(selectRange);
  const values = range.getValues();
  const styles = values.map(r => {
    let ar = Array(r.length).fill(tempStyle);
    ar[r.lastIndexOf(Math.max(...r))] = bold;
    return ar;
  });
  range.setTextStyles(styles);
}
```

Comment: Your understanding is right except for one thing :
I dont want to analyse all values in one time, I want to have the maximum value for each row individually. So the maximum of row 1 is different than row 2 ... etc

Comment: @Saku Thank you for replying. From your replying, in my sample script, the maximum value is retrieved from each row and the text style is set every row. So I cannot understand about your replying. Can I ask you about the detail of the issue of my sample script?

Comment: @Saku As a test case, when my script is run for your sample sheet in your question (the header column and header row are the row 1 and column "A"),  for the rows 2, 3 and 4, the columns "D", "C" and "C" are set with the bold style, respectively. I understood that this situation is your goal. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Your script seems to work well but is it possible to specify a certain range ? Because I got strings in other cells that may occurs with the script ? Also it works great but not on all my array (the first 7 row are not affected)
Check that screen : https://prnt.sc/s07iic

Comment: @Saku Thank you for replying. My sample script is from your sample values in your question. I deeply apologize for this. From your replying, I added one more sample script. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the result you want, I apologize again.

Comment: Don't even apologize ! You are doing a great job and everything seems to work like it should ! I greatly thank you for all your time and experience ! You save me lot of time trying to get this to work ! 
1000 thanks !

Comment: @Saku Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, unfortunately, I cannot understand about your replying. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this. So in order to correctly understand about it. can you post it as new question by including the detail information? By this, I would like to confirm it and think of the solution.

Comment: @Saku Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. From your replying, I cannot still understand about the detail of your new question. But I would like to support you. So can you post it as new question by including the detail information? I would like to confirm and understand about it.

Comment: Thank you for helping me, so I deleted last comments that talk about that and create new question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61270477/script-get-highest-value-in-a-string Hope this would help you better